# Link properly a library using cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I try to learn how to use cmake, and so I created a little project but when I try to compile I get this error : `/usr/bin/ld : CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o : dans la fonction « main » : main.cpp:(.text+0x2d) : référence indéfinie vers « la::Matrice<int>::Matrice(unsigned int, unsigned int) »`

```
.
├── build
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── LinearAlgebra
│   └── Makefile
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── LinearAlgebra
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── Matrice.cpp
│   └── Matrice.hpp
└── main.cpp
```

./CmakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED true)

project(test_project)


add_subdirectory(LinearAlgebra)



add_executable(test main.cpp)
link_libraries(test linear_algebra)
```

LinearAlgebra/CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(linear_algebra)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)

set(SOURCES
    Matrice.cpp

)

set(HEADERS
    Matrice.hpp
)

add_library(linear_algebra ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
```

Do someone know where the problem is ?

Comment: For link `test` executable with `linear_algebra` library you need to use `target_link_libraries` command. The command `link_libraries` list libraries for link with them all **further** executables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_libraries.html) you define which libraries will be linked for targets that are defined *after* this command and within the current directory.

You probably meant to use [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) which defines libraries to link to the given target.
The documentation suggests to use this over `link_libraries` whenever possible. It is explicit and better scoped.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED true)
project(test_project)
add_subdirectory(LinearAlgebra)
add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test linear_algebra)
```